# Creating a scheduled reboot task every Saturday of the week

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I have no issues setting up a scheduled task every week (Saturday) at 3pm, however there is a requirement that if the last day of the month falls on a Saturday, the reboot has to be rolled over to Sunday at 3pm.

This is the part I am unsure of, as task scheduler doesn't appear to have an exclude option, so wondering what my options are?

Comment: Write a Script that runs every Saturday and only initiates a reboot if it's not the last day of the month. Same with Sunday, but only reboots if it is the first of the month.

Comment: @Mikoyan  you have asked several question on StackOverFlow over the years and you do not seem to accept any of the answers provided as an answer to your question.  Please go back and do so.

Comment: Flagged down as this question never received an acceptance.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the same concept that Matsnow provided but done as a batch file.  Powershell has lots of object oriented functions builtin so the batch file is a bit more code.

```
@Echo off

REM Get Date and Time
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set yyyy=%dt:~0,4%
set mm=%dt:~4,2%
set dd=%dt:~6,2%

REM Get Last Day of month
call :DaysOfMonth %yyyy% %mm%

IF "%lastday%"=="%dd%" (
    shutdown /r /t 86400
) else (
    shutdown /r /t 0
)
GOTO :EOF

:DaysOfMonth Year Month
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set /a "yy = %~1, mm = 100%~2 %% 100"
set /a "n = 30 + !(((mm & 9) + 6) %% 7) + !(mm ^ 2) * (!(yy %% 4) - !(yy %% 100) + !(yy %% 400) - 2)"
endlocal &set lastday=%n%
GOTO :EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to run a script and check if the current date is the last day of the month.

If yes, wait 24 hours with reboot, if no reboot immediately.

The following Powershell-script will do what you want. Run it every Saturday at 3pm.

```
#Get the last day of the current month
$lastDayOfMonth = ((Get-Date).AddMonths(1)).
                   AddDays(-(Get-Date ((Get-Date).AddMonths(1)) -format dd)).Date

if ((Get-Date).Date -eq $lastDayOfMonth)
{
    #It's the last day of this month, reboot in 24 hours (86400 seconds)
    shutdown -r -t 86400
}
else
{
    #Reboot immediately
    shutdown -r -t 0
}
```

Another solution may be a third-party task scheduler software.

Comment: This is assuming a windows machine, the OP has a scheduler and if it is linux then cron is mostly likely the scheduler. Use "crontab -e" to schedule a task as the user and follow the guide for cronjobs. https://linuxconfig.org/linux-crontab-reference-guide

Comment: As the other answer does too. The question is clearly tagged with `windows`, so i don't get your point.

Answer (score 0):

```
$Sta = Register-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "\" -Description "reboot" -Action "powershell" -RunLevel Highest -TaskName "reboot" -Settings "restart-computer -force" #<-- something like this...
$Stt = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -weekly -WeeksInterval 1 -DaysOfWeek "Saturday" -At 4:00am;
Set-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "\" $tasknames -Trigger $Stt -Force -User domain\*** -Password ***
```